# I get (An internal error has occurred. [Requests from this Android client applicaiont xxx.xxx.xxx] are blocked!) in my debug mode only

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, sha1

I have searched all over the internet there several solutions to this specific issue but no luck my case. In my case the release version works absolutely fine but when I run a debug version of it even I generated an SHA-1 certificate for the debug.keystore and then added it into my Firebase Project but it did not resolve my issue. I already have added 2 more SHA-1 as release versions which are working but debug is not working. Please help me in this case.

**THIS IS WHAT I GET AS AN ERROR ON RUN:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLqfU.png)

**AND THESE ARE MY SHA-1 CERTIFIATES BLUE LINED ARE WORKING BUT THE RED LINED IS NOT WORKING**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMwBl.png)

Here is the list of libraries I used in this project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUffx.png)

This is where I have enabled the Google Auth:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRds6.png)

Please do help me in this scenario I am stuck since 4 or more days. I have to debug it for more time and deadline is quite near please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I was thinking I found the solution myself which was to add SHA-1 certificate into the Cloud Console where all API SERVICES resides.

How to add SHA-1 into your API Key:

1: Open Google Cloud
2: Select Your Project
3: Click on API (APIs & Services)
4: Click On Credentials
5: Edit Your API Key
6: Scroll Down To The (**Android restrictions**)
7: Click On +ADD Button
8: Provide Your Package Name
9: Provide Your SHA-1 Certificate
10: Click On Done
11: Click On SAVE Button

This will resolve your issue!

Editional:
HOW TO GET SHA-1 Certificate:
1: Find and Open JAVA Bin Folder (C:\Program Files\JAVA\jdk-version\bin)
2: Write Click On Empty Space Inside Folder While Holding Shift Button
3: Click on Open PowerShell window here
4: Type KeyTool Command:
.\keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\your-username.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
5: You'll Find SHA-1 Certificate After Command Finished Generation.